# Elementor Wordpress plugin randomly adds the word "array" to my custom widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm building a custom widget for elementor to help my client add items to the website on his own without coding knowledge. I almost had it finished when I ran into a very strange issue. A button I have set up to link to a new page is putting the text "array" into itself for some reason.

I've tried putting in text where the "array" text is directly by editing my html. When I update or go into preview mode on wordpress this text disappears and the word "array" reappears. I even went so far as to add a field on the button where my client or I can add our own text in an attempt to solve the problem, but now that text is just preceded by "array".

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

All my relevant code is in my awesomesauce.php file where the code for my widget is

```
<?php
namespace ElementorAwesomesauce\Widgets;

use Elementor\Widget_Base;
use Elementor\Controls_Manager;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

/**
 * @since 1.1.0
 */
class Awesomesauce extends Widget_Base {

  /**
   * Retrieve the widget name.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access public
   *
   * @return string Widget name.
   */
  public function get_name() {
    return 'awesomesauce';
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the widget title.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access public
   *
   * @return string Widget title.
   */
  public function get_title() {
    return __( 'Awesomesauce', 'elementor-awesomesauce' );
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the widget icon.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access public
   *
   * @return string Widget icon.
   */
  public function get_icon() {
    return 'fa fa-pencil';
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the list of categories the widget belongs to.
   *
   * Used to determine where to display the widget in the editor.
   *
   * Note that currently Elementor supports only one category.
   * When multiple categories passed, Elementor uses the first one.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access public
   *
   * @return array Widget categories.
   */
  public function get_categories() {
    return [ 'general' ];
  }

  /**
   * Register the widget controls.
   *
   * Adds different input fields to allow the user to change and customize the widget settings.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function _register_controls() {
    $this->start_controls_section(
      'section_content',
      [
        'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
      ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
      'title',
      [
        'label' => __( 'Title', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
        'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
        'default' => __( 'Car Title', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
      ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
      'description',
      [
        'label' => __( 'Description', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
        'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXTAREA,
        'default' => __( 'Sold or Currently available', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
      ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
      'content',
      [
        'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
        'type' => Controls_Manager::WYSIWYG,
        'default' => __( 'Remove this text and insert media', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
      ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
            'link',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Link', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::URL,
                'dynamic' => [
                    'active' => true,
                ],
                'placeholder' => __( 'https://your-link.com', 'elementor-awesomesauce' ),
                'default' => [
                    'url' => '#',
                ],

            ]
        );

    $this->add_control(
            'text',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Text', 'elementor' ),
                'type' => Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'dynamic' => [
                    'active' => true,
                ],
                'default' => __( 'Click here', 'elementor' ),
                'placeholder' => __( 'Click here', 'elementor' ),
            ]
        );


    $this->end_controls_section();
  }

  /**
   * Render the widget output on the frontend.
   *
   * Written in PHP and used to generate the final HTML.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( 'title', 'none' );
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( 'description', 'basic' );
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( 'content', 'advanced' );
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( 'link', 'none');
    $this->add_inline_editing_attributes( 'text', 'basic');

    // Add render attributes to add classes to html elements h2, article, figure, and div

    $this->add_render_attribute( 'title', 'class', 'title is-5');
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'description', 'class', 'subtitle');
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'content', 'class', 'image is-4by3');
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'link', 'class', 'button is-rounded is-fullwidth');

    $this->add_render_attribute( 'wrapper', 'class', 'tile is-parent');
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'wrappertwo', 'class', 'tile is-child box');
    $this->add_render_attribute( 'text', 'class', 'subtitle has-text-right');

    ?>

    <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'wrapper' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['wrapper']; ?>
      <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'wrappertwo' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['wrappertwo']; ?>
        <h2 <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'title' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['title']; ?></h2>
        <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'description' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['description']; ?></div>
        <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'content' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['content']; ?></div>
        <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'link' ); ?>><?php echo $settings['link']; ?>
          <div <?php echo $this->get_render_attribute_string( 'text'); ?>><?php echo $settings['text']; ?></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <?php
  }

  /**
   * Render the widget output in the editor.
   *
   * Written as a Backbone JavaScript template and used to generate the live preview.
   *
   * @since 1.1.0
   *
   * @access protected
   */
  protected function _content_template() {
    ?>
    <#
    view.addInlineEditingAttributes( 'title', 'none' );
    view.addInlineEditingAttributes( 'description', 'basic' );
    view.addInlineEditingAttributes( 'content', 'advanced' );
    view.addInlineEditingAttributes( 'car_image', 'advanced');
    #>
    <div ' + view.getRenderAttributeString( 'wrapper' ) + ' >
      <article ' + view.getRenderAttributeString( 'wrappertwo' ) + ' >
        <h2 class="title is-5" {{{ view.getRenderAttributeString( 'title' ) }}}>{{{ settings.title }}}</h2>
        <div class="subtitle" {{{ view.getRenderAttributeString( 'description' ) }}}>{{{ settings.description }}}</div>
        <figure class="image is-4by3" {{{ view.getRenderAttributeString( 'content' ) }}}>{{{ settings.content }}}</figure>
            <a href="{{ settings.link.url }}" class="button is-rounded is-fullwidth">
              <span {{{ view.getRenderAttributeString( 'text' ) }}}>{{{ settings.text }}}</span>
            </a>
      </article>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```

No idea whats causing this. Hopefully its something stupid that will be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Liton Arefin figured it out in another post I made in the wordpress stack exchange about this same issue. Here's a link to the fix.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348086/174997